# How to do mouse hover in geb spock

Tags: spock, geb

I am using geb spock and trying to hover an element, however I am getting error. Below are details.
Page Object Class

```
class HomePage extends Page {

    static at ={
        title.contains("Activity Dashboard")
    }

    static content = {
        tabConnections (wait : true) {$("a", "class" : contains("dropdown-toggle"), "text" : "Connections")}
        subMenuManageConnections (wait: true) {tabConnections.find("ul").find("a" , "href": "/managecash/EDGE_Network" , "text" : "Manage Connections")}
    }


    public void mouseHoverMethod(){
        waitFor {tabConnections.displayed}

        Actions actions = new Actions(driver)
        actions.moveToElement(tabConnections).build().perform()
    }
}
```

When I am calling mouseHoverMethod method from my spock spec file, getting below error message:
on line (`actions.moveToElement(tabConnections).build().perform()`) as below:

Error Message:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.moveToElement() is applicable
>   for argument types: (geb.content.TemplateDerivedPageContent) values:
>   [pageobjects.general.HomePage -> tabConnections:
>   geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator]
>       Possible solutions: moveToElement(org.openqa.selenium.WebElement), moveToElement(org.openqa.selenium.WebElement, int, int)

Can you please help me how mouse hovering can be done in Geb Spock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@kriegaex, @erdi.
Thanks for your solutions. I am also able to find one working solution and created below methods in page object. All three methods are working fine.

```
public void mouseHoverMethodOne (TemplateDerivedPageContent element){
        waitFor {element}
        element.jquery.mouseover()
        element.click()
    }

public void mouseHoverMethodTwo (TemplateDerivedPageContent element){
        waitFor {element.displayed}
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver)
        actions.moveToElement(element.firstElement()).build().perform()
        element.click()
    }

public void mouseHoverMethodThree (TemplateDerivedPageContent element){
        waitFor {element.displayed}
        interact {
            moveToElement(element)
        }
        element.click()
    }
```

Thanks for your help on this. I have rated your answers too, as those give me lot of insights.

Comment: Welcome. Maybe instead of just copy & paste harvesting solutions into your threefold recap you could just accept one of the answers offered. Whether you do "first come, first serve" or like to pick another favourite is up to you, of course.

Comment: @kriegaex, I agree. Nice that you summed it up Durgesh but it's right to give credits by accepting their (First come, first serve) answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use Geb's interact block, see http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#complex-interactions

Your method would then look like ->

```
public void mouseHoverMethod(){
    waitFor {tabConnections.displayed}
    interact {
        moveToElement(tabConnections)
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that [`moveToElement()` inside of `interact {}` blocks takes a `Navigator` as the first argument](http://gebish.org/manual/current/api/geb/interaction/InteractDelegate.html#moveToElement(geb.navigator.Navigator)) so there is no need to call `firstElement()` on `tabConnections` and the call can be simplified to `moveToElement(tabConnections)`.

Comment: Updated per erdi's advice.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you that you are providing a `TemplateDerivedPageContent` instance (`tabConnections`) to the `moveToElement()` method. But if you check the method's signature you see that is expects a `WebElement` argument. Of course Selenium WebDriver does not know anything about Geb-specific classes. Thus, you have to get the web element from your navigator like this:

```java
actions.moveToElement(tabConnections.firstElement()).build().perform()
```